# Force loading an image to stop flickering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

When using the jQuery .hover() function to switch out two images, I often find a flicker when they are being switched on the first load. I assume this is because the second of the two isn't loaded along with the main page, and so the transition isn't completely smooth and there's a slight flicker.

In theory, this should be then rectifiable by placing a 1px by 1px image with `display: none;` set as styling, which will load the image when the main page loads, thus cacheing it at the same time and removing the flicker.

However, I'm wondering if there's any other/better solutions that are commonly used to force an image to load, as surely I'm not the only one who has this issue.

Any comments or advice would be greatly appreciated :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A far better way to prevent hover image flickering is to use [**CSS sprites**](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp).

Even if you decide to use JavaScript to achieve the hovering effect (although hover effect is perfectly achievable with plain CSS ) you will still have your "second" (hovered) image loaded by the time it needs to be displayed.

Comment: Please don't feed w3schools.com, [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites) and [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/158-css-sprites/) would be better references.

Comment: If you choose a CSS-only approach (which is often a good idea), beware that IE6 (annoyingly) doesn't support the `:hover` pseudo-class on anything but `a` tags

Comment: Why exactly is w3schools a bad reference? Its a good starting point and even if its considered a bad reference by some the answer still gives the most important keywords to search for **CSS sprites**.

Comment: @mu is too short: Agreed! I'll just leave this link here for the public's benefit: http://w3fools.com/

Comment: @holodoc: w3schools is _always_ among the first search results when you google something, but that doesn't mean it's a good reference. It just means they're good at optimizing for Google. But W3S is full of errors, and often perpetuates bad practices. See the ful explanation at the site I linked to above (which also recommends better sources)

Comment: @Flambino Well then we'll just have to hope that he is hovering over <a> tags or at least comes to his senses and in the interest of his health ignores IE6 completely ;)

Comment: @Flambino Calm down. W3Schools might not be the best reference on the web but its still good for quick reference.

Comment: @holodoc: I'm calm, I'm just trying to help. You _did_ ask why W3S is bad, so I answered. And yes, W3S can be good for a few basic things (like, if you can't remember if some tag supports a specific attribute or not), but if you can't be sure that what they're saying is actually correct it's a bigger hassle than it's worth.

Comment: @holodoc: Oh, and we're totally in agreement on IE6 by the way :)

Comment: The more links there are to W3S, the longer they stay at the top of Google's search results and the longer they get to mislead and misinform people. By linking to them, you're supporting their nonsense and I think we have a professional responsibility to do better.  I'm not flaming you or anything, just clarifying the general feeling about W3S.

Comment: i got suckered into trying w3school's instructions on css sprite creation. their example didn't work at all for me. the one at CSS Tricks did.

this crap doesn't work:
background:url('img_navsprites.gif') -47px 0;

this does:
background-position: -47px 0px;

Answer (score 2):

As already answered by holodoc CSS sprites would help you a lot...

Do you just use the jQuery.hover() for image switching? If yes, you may use the CSS :hover pseudo selector.

Comment: No it to enact additional events asides from image switching, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You should only have to preload it with something like the following:

```
var preloadImg = new Image()
preloadImg.src = "/path/to/image.jpg"
```

Then, if it still flickers, create two HTML nodes that have each image and then switch between them.