# How to set one minute counter in javascript?

Tags: javascript, counter, countdown

In my project ,I have list of questions, for every question have three option answers.

After see the question  if i want answer that question means click "show answer" button .
when I click button ,counter starts for one minute after one minute error will show .

can any one help ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
function gameLost() {
  alert("You lose!");
}
setTimeout(gameLost, 60000);
```

**UPDATE:** pass function reference to `setTimeout()` instead of code string (did I really write it that way? O_o)

---

EDIT

To display the timer too (improved version, thanks to davin too):

```
<button onclick="onTimer()">Clickme</button>
<div id="mycounter"></div>
<script>
i = 60;
function onTimer() {
  document.getElementById('mycounter').innerHTML = i;
  i--;
  if (i < 0) {
    alert('You lose!');
  }
  else {
    setTimeout(onTimer, 1000);
  }
}
</script>
```

......

Comment: It's recommended where possible to send function references to `setTimeout` and not strings, since they're `eval`ed which is slow and unsafe. In this case, it's also shorter to just write `setTimeout(gameLost, 60000)`

Comment: @davin: does this work? Usually, I use jQuery so I don't remember usage of these "standard" functions.. I quickly checked documentation that doesn't mention that.

Comment: If it didn't work, I wouldn't suggest it :) See https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.setTimeout the syntax clearly says `func` and describes it as a function. Plus, they clearly state that the string version is not recommended. But if you want to be 100% sure, look at their examples; it is exactly the same structure as yours and they do what I suggested.

Comment: If anyone interested, that's what I come out with after playing a bit with that code.. :) http://stuff.hackzine.org/misc-code/js-timeout.html

Answer (score 8):

```
function timedOut() {
    alert("Some error message");
}

// set a timer
setTimeout( timedOut , 60000 );
```

That basically sets a timer that will execute the given function after 60.000 miliseconds = 60 seconds = 1 minute

Edit: here's a quick, imperfect fiddle that also shows the countdown http://jsfiddle.net/HRrYG

```
function countdown() {
    var seconds = 60;
    function tick() {
        var counter = document.getElementById("counter");
        seconds--;
        counter.innerHTML = "0:" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + String(seconds);
        if( seconds > 0 ) {
            setTimeout(tick, 1000);
        } else {
            alert("Game over");
        }
    }
    tick();
}

// start the countdown
countdown();
```

Comment: +1 for being first (you beat me by about five seconds, but given my answer was the same as yours I didn't post it).

Comment: First argument to `setTimeout()` is a JavaScript statement, not a callback.. so it should be `'timedOut()'` instead

Comment: @Flambino . Thanks . I am also need to display the timer .

Comment: @redShadow: No, opposite. Using a string of javascript code is the outdated method of doing it. Passing a callback is the preferred way of doing it.

Comment: @Flambino, sorry, you are right. I quickly checked documentation (on stupid w3schools...) that did not mention that..

Comment: @redShadow: Why are you looking at W3S when [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript) is available?

Comment: @KarthickTerror: Well, you didn't say anything about that in your question, but ok... here's a jsfiddle that pretty much does that http://jsfiddle.net/HRrYG/

Comment: @muistooshort: heh, wasn't it just yesterday that you warned against W3S over on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886031/force-loading-an-image-to-stop-flickering/6886048 ? :)

Comment: @Flambino: I think I did a couple other times today too, just fighting the good fight for decent documentation :)

Comment: @muistooshort: I couldn't agree more, so by all means keep it up :)

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use the setTimout function check out this article.  https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.setTimeout Remember the timer is in milliseconds so for one minute is 60,000.

Answer (score 0):

// this is the simplest way to one mint counter .this is also use in angular and oops

```
var i=60;
function coundown(){
   setInterval(() => {
  if (this.i == 0) {
    return;
  }
  console.log(this.i--);

}, 1000);
}
```

// this function you can call when otp is comming or form submit and waiting for otp countdown

## angular #javascript #typescript

Answer (score 0):

#### you can try to use this

### or visit for more details [Demo](https://codepen.io/mrana/pen/GRqzPdZ)

[Demo2](https://www.facebook.com/mswebmart)

```js
function countdown() {
        var seconds = 59;
        function tick() {
          var counter = document.getElementById("counter");
          seconds--;
          counter.innerHTML =
            "0:" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + String(seconds);
          if (seconds > 0) {
            setTimeout(tick, 1000);
          } else {
            document.getElementById("verifiBtn").innerHTML = `
                <div class="Btn" id="ResendBtn">
                    <button type="submit">Resend</button>
                </div>
            `;
            document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = "";
          }
        }
        tick();
      }
      countdown();
```

```html
<div class="btnGroup">
        <span class="Btn" id="verifiBtn">
          <button type="submit">Verify</button>
        </span>
        <span class="timer">
          <span id="counter"></span>
        </span>
      </div>
```